# Table forces following text onto next page after editing in LibreOffice

Tags: google-docs

I created a document in Google Docs, downloaded in [Open Document Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument), edited with [LibreOffice Writer](https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/writer/), then uploaded the edited document back to Google Docs.  In the new document:

- There exists a table which causes the following text to be pushed onto the next page, rather than immediately after the table.
- If new tables are inserted after the first table, they stay on the same page rather than being pushed onto the next page like the ordinary text is.
- If the table is deleted the text flows properly again.

  - If a new table is inserted the problem comes back.
- If enough of the following text is deleted the problem also goes away.
- These problems don't exist in the original document.

[Here is a copy of the problem document, with the text before the problem area removed](https://docs.google.com/document/d/11-9nuZGUHAlwwCVC6rG7hYCsEWy5Npc2N3P-QX43m8Q/edit?usp=sharing)